# How to write this equation in terms of sine only?

Tags: trigonometry

Write the expression : $$-\sqrt{3}\sin x+\cos x$$ in terms of sine function only.

The answer is $2\sin (x+\frac{5\pi}{6})$ .Just wondering how you get to that point.

Comment: edit your question and write your efforts.

Comment: Hello. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15078#15078) for equations and explain what you've tried

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y+ \cos x \sin y$.

Comment: Multiply and divide the proposed expression by $2$ and apply the suggestion of @user

Comment: See [harmonic addition theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html)

Comment: Does "in terms of sine only" allow $-\sqrt{3}\sin x+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$?

Comment: This is not an equation but an expression

Answer (score 4):

First, recall the trigonometric identity $\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x$.
Now try to bring your expression in the form of the right side of the equation.
Use the fact that $\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = {-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ as well as $\sin (\frac{5\pi}{6})=\frac{1}{2} $
\begin{align*}
-\sqrt{3}\sin x + \cos x = 2 \left(- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin x + \frac{1}{2}\cos x \right) =2\left(\cos \left(\frac{5\pi}{6} \right)\sin x + \sin \left(\frac{5\pi}{6} \right) \cos x\right) \\ = 2 \sin \left(\frac{5\pi}{6}+ x \right)
\end{align*}